# Null type in standard C++ library

Tags: c++, parameters, null, arguments

Is there some special null type and value in standard C++ library, e.g. defined as `struct null_type_t {};`?

I want to use it in different places to signify that there is no value passed.

E.g. to use in next template:

```
template <typename T = std::null_type_t>
struct S {};
```

Or in structure like next:

```
template <typename T>
struct Optional {
    constexpr Optional() = delete;
    constexpr Optional(std::null_type_t) {}
    template <typename OT>
    constexpr Optional(OT const & val)
        : has_value(true), value(val) {}
    bool const has_value = false;
    T const value = T();
};
```

Basically if `std::null_type_t` type or value is passed as template or function parameter then my code will do some special handling, i.e. this null type signifies that there is no value.

Of cause I can define in my code my own struct like next:

```
struct NullType {};
```

But I did this kind of definition in code many times already. And maybe there exists special standard library type for this kind of thing, which I can use everywhere instead of my definition of null struct.

There is `nullptr_t` type and `nullptr` value, that I can use in some places. But not all, because if function or template parameter is a pointer type then sometimes I want to pass null pointer to signify real value of null pointer, not the absence of value. That's why for such pointer-typed cases would be good to have some separate type like `struct null_type_t {};` which doesn't interfere with pointer or any other class or built-in type.

Comment: You'll be surprised to learn that the "structure like next" happens to be called `std::optional`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, my structure is capable to be used as non-type template parameter in this code `template <Optional<size_t> X = nullptr> struct S {};`, but standard std::optional can't be used in such place, that's why I implemented my own. Also it is just an example of usage, it is not related to question itself about null type.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, so I deleted my answer. `std::optional` uses `std::nullopt_t` for this purpose: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t So for your own optional type, you should probably implement your own `nullopt_t`.

Comment: @NikosC. Wow! `nullopt_t` and `nullopt` looks like something that I need! Thanks! Can you create answer for that so that I can accept?

Comment: @NikosC. BTW, I want to use null type not only for implementing my `Optional` variant. But in any code that needs to sometimes handle some Null special value separately. So I want to have some Null for any case, not just Optional helper. Is there such Null in standard library? But anyway nullopt_t looks good for such cases.

Comment: Can't you just pass an empty `Optional` for that? That's what the idea of an optional is there for.

Comment: @NikosC. Imagine `NoneType` type and `None` value in Python. They are used to signify that there is no value for variable or element of structure. Also there is same `null` in JavaScript. Probably any scripting language has such null. So I want to find standard Null in C++ somewhere too.

Comment: @NikosC. No, Optional can't be passed always. I need special separate handling of Null. One example is high performance appications, first std::optional should be initialized always, it means if I have some huge structure it needs to be copied into std::optional just to be passed into my function. Basically std::optional is runtime solution. But I need to signify absence of value in compile time. Also I don't want to copy whole structure into std::optional just to signify to my function absence or presence of value.

Comment: @NikosC. Also, drawback of std::optional that it can't be used as non-type template parameter. For that I implemented my `Optional` in my question/post above, which can be passed. But that all unrelated, I just want at compile time to have some Null type and value that I will handle somehow separately. Of cause if I have at run time some vector then sure I need to use `std::vector<std::optional<Class>>`, I understand that. But for compile time I need some null type and value separately.

Comment: @NikosC. Any way, seems that std::nullopt_t type and std::nullopt value is something that is suitable for me. Thanks!

Comment: In standard C++, there's also [std::monostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate), via `#include <variant>`.  May be of use, interest, or just good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::optional` uses `std::nullopt_t` for this purpose: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t

So for your own optional type, you should probably implement your own `nullopt_t`.

Comment: No, this is what `std::optional` is for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, that too :)

Comment: `void` can't be passed as function argument to signify no value. As type name it can be passed. But unfortunately there is no value for this void type. Look into my question, there is example `constexpr Optional(std::null_type_t) {}` which uses null type by value. I want same null value to be passed to some functions. And `void` can never be used by value, only as type.

Comment: @Arty you also have a member of type `T`, so anyhow you need to specialize the template for the case `T=void`

Comment: @Arty or is this just what you want? A type like `void` but there can be objects of that type?

Comment: Yes, thanks! std::nullopt_t type and std::nullopt value are exactly what I need. Accepting and UpVoting answer!